# Universal Lossless Compression?

Tags: algorithms, data-compression, check-my-answer

It is not possible to losslessly compress all files of size $n$ using a single algorithm, as there are more files of size $n (2^n)$ than of size $p, p: p < n ( 2^n-1)$. Via the pigeon hole principle, if we only tried to compress files of size $n$ with a single algorithm, there would be at least one file it was impossible to compress.

If we wanted to be able to compress files with differing lengths $n_k$, the number of files of length $n_k$ we can compress for each $n_k$ becomes even smaller.

Today when reading a story about how a file that was several gigabytes when compressed uncompressed to one gigabyte, I had an idea for a universal compression algorithm.

---

Let $a_i$ be a compression algorithm.
Let $g_j$ be a file.
$|g_j|$ denotes the length of $g_j$.
Let $f(a_i, g_j)$ be a function that returns $(|g_j| - |a_i(g_j)|)$.

Let $S_N = \{g_j : |g_j| \le N\}$.

Let $A =  \{a_i : \, \forall \, g_j \in S_N \, \exists a_i in A : f(a_i, g_j) \gt \lceil(\log_2{\#A})\rceil\}$.
$\#A$ denotes the number of elements in $A$.

Let $m$ be the length of the label of the compression algorithm chosen. The first $m$ bytes of every compressed file denote the compression algorithm chosen.
$m = \lceil(\log_2{\#A})\rceil$.

Then you can compress all $g_j \in S_N$, by iterating through A until you find $a_i : f(a_i,g_j) - m \gt 0$.

Even better.

For each $g_j$, let $a_j$ be the corresponding compression algorithm.

Let $h(a_i, g_j) = f(a_i,g_j) - m$.

$${ \, \forall \, a_i \in A, g_j \in S_N, a_j = \displaystyle{ \underset{a_i \in A, g_j \in S} { \operatorname{argmax} } } \, (h(a_i, g_j))}$$

---

Is there a reason why the above is not done?

While the above is an algorithm, and one could argue that the pigeon hole principle thus applies, this does not imply what it may at first seem to imply.  The above algorithm call it $a^v$ is a little different.

Let $a_i: S_N \to Y_N^i$ denote that algorithm $a_i$ maps a family of files $(S_N = \{g_j : |g_j| \le N\})$ is mapped to another family of files $Y_N = \{y_j : y_j = a_i(g_j)\}$.

$\forall a_i \in A, a_i: S_N \to Y_N^i$.
However, $a^v : S_{N+m} \to Y_{N+m}^v$.
So $a^v$ compresses a different family of files from $a_i \ in A$.

The pigeon hole principle merely states that $a^v$ cannot compress all files of length $N+m$; this is irrelevant, since $a^v$ only intends to compress a small subset of files of length $N+m$ (those whose first $m$ bits are the labels of some $a_i \in A$.

Comment: Please state upfront what you suppose your envisioned `universal compression algorithm` to achieve: can any input be thrown at it - and be reconstructed faithfully?

Comment: @greybeard no, only files in $S_N$.

Comment: Again, please add to your question: *What does* this `universal compression algorithm` achieve? What makes $S_N$ relevant/interesting? (My answer to `why the above is not done?`: irrelevant/not interesting.)

Comment: $S_N$ is simply the set of files whose length is less than or equal to $N$. The above algorithm allows you to compress all files in $S_N$. You can set $N$ to be as large as you want.

Comment: It is the same as stated theory. You have just picked convenient samples that are compressible. There is no contradiction here, but it is not practical and it is no longer universal. If you wish to apply it recursively then you will find out that the description of selected algorithms evens out the compressed gains.

Comment: @Evil $m = \lceil\log_2{\#A}\rceil$, so the $m$ bits used to describe the algorithm chosen grows logarithmically slower than the number of algorithms to choose from. This the description of the algorithm should not nullify the gains in compression from choosing from among many algorithms?

Comment: @TobiAlafin You cannot compress all files of length at most $N$ for the same reason that you cannot compress all files. There are $2^{N+1}-1$ files that you need to compress. If you compress every file of length at most $N$, then every compressed file must have length strictly less than $N$. But there are only $2^N-1$ such files, which isn't enough.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, but I am using a different algorithm. I am not compressing all files of length $N$; I am compressing a subset of files of length $N + m$. The extra $m$ bits denote the compression algorithm chosen. We choose a compression algorithm from among a family of compression algorithms. Like the entire post after the first paragraph was a way to get around the pigeon hole principle. It may still apply, but I am not seeing an argument for why it still applies. I am not compressing files of length $n$, I am compressing files of length $N + m$ (and a very small subset of them at that).

Comment: You say "Then we can compress all $g_j\in S_n$", which is a claim of universal lossless compression. The impossibility of universal lossless compression has nothing to do with algorithms: it is a simple matter of the cardinality of sets. "Choose an algorithm from a family of algorithms" is still an algorithm: `if property_1 then compress_with_algo_1; else if property_2 then compress_with_algo_2; else...` That doesn't help anything: it's still an algorithm and no algorithm can compress everything.

Comment: @DavidRicherby $a^v$ compresses files of length $N+m$, and only a subset of those files. It can't compress all files of length $n+m$, but it can compress some of them (precisely those files of length $N + m$ that correspond to files of length $N$.

Comment: You claim that you have an algorithm that can compress all files of length $N$. It doesn't matter what that algorithm does. You know that no such algorithm can exist.

Comment: Not really, it is either not universal or not working. provably. The only missing point is that you think it might be universal, because the second you know already (as stated in the question). If "repack" say all powers of 2 and store only exponent, it will work for selected family, but won't work for other inputs. If you add numbers of the form $2^n + 1$ it will independently work for this family, but you have to store 2 bits to indicate so, say 00 for not compressed, 01 for powers of two and 10 for shifted by one. Calculating for fixed $n$ will yield more mean bits per sample.

Answer (score 2):

> Then you can compress all $g_j ∈ S_N$, by iterating through $A$ until you find $a_i|f(a_i,g_j)−m>0$.

I'm not sure what the notation means (the pipe here, and also $\#A$ elsewhere), but still: this is not a meaningful algorithm since the set

> $\qquad A = \{a_i : \, \forall \, g_j \in S_N \, f(a_i, g_j) \gt \lceil(\log_2{\#A})\rceil\}$

is empty.

I think you got lost in notation. $S_N$ = $\Sigma^{\leq n}$ and $A$ is the set of all algorithms that compress *all* strings in $S_N$ by at least some non-zero number of bits. As you cited, there are no such algorithms.

In the updated question, you write:

> $\qquad A =  \{a_i : \, \forall \, g_j \in S_N \, \exists a_i \in A : f(a_i, g_j) \gt \lceil(\log_2{\#A})\rceil\}$

This definition is circular, hence $A$ is not well-defined. Did you mean

$\qquad A = \{ a \mid \exists g \in S_N. f(a, g) > x \}$

with $x > 0$ something that does *not* depend on $A$?

Now $A$ is infinite (and undecidable as per Rice's theorem) and, arguably, completely useless: any string `s` can be compressed well by the trivial algorithm

```
compress_s(x) {
    if x == s
        return "0"
    else
        return "0" + x
    end
}
```

Note that this version of $A$ contains all these bogus algorithms. So, you have thrown all information while compressing, instead encoding the string in the algorithm's source code (mathematically and literally).

And, as others note, the resulting algorithm would *still* be subject to the pidgeon-hole principle.

> Is there a reason why the above is not done?

Even if it were possible, it'd be horribly inefficient. In essence, the idea of your algorithm is:

> Try all (compression) algorithms (I know); pick the smallest result and encode the result together with its code.

That's clearly neither a clever nor a useful algorithmic idea.

Comment: Do you think that Kolmogorov complexity might be good to describe here? The last paragraph pictures that case ;)

Comment: @TobiAlafin You need to make up your mind about what you want to define *before* posting questions about it, and make sure you *know* what you are defining. Otherwise you're wasting everbody's time. This is the last edit I'll do; you've been given enough explanations for why what you think you're doing is impossible.

Comment: @Evil I don't see an immediate connection; if you do, why not post an answer?